# Why Disable-AzureRmVMDiskEncryption doesn't need either key encryption key or disk encryption key urls

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-disk

The Disable-AzureRmVMDiskEncryption cmdlet (I believe disable = decryption) just needs a name of the VM to disable encryption.

Isn't it a security issue disabling encryption without any key ? How can the disks be safeguarded from disabling encryption, through RBAC ?

Comment: Encryption at rest adds very little security because the key is as accessible as the data to any attacker. It is a scam designed to comply with regulations by pretending to be more secure by using "encryption". Encryption with the key sitting next to the data is worthless.

Comment: I think thats where the key encryption key (kek) is helpful. Encrypt the disk encryption key with kek and protect it. But if is no proper RBAC applied to VM encryption permissions, anyone who has access to the VM would be able to decrypt it using Disable-AzureRmVMDiskEncryption command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it a security issue disabling encryption without any key ?

It doesn't look like a security concern because there are two separate concerns at play here:

1. Protecting Data at rest - which is taken care of by Azure Disk Encryption (only if you enable it as per Azure Data Security and Encryption Best Practices)
2. Protecting access to VM itself and it's resources - which is taken care of by RBAC.

**When you Disable Disk Encryption**

It does actually make sure that currently encrypted data gets decrypted back and is no longer encrypted at rest.

Since Azure already knows the details about the Key Encryption Key (KEK) and Disk Encryption Key (DEK) details from the time you enable the encryption in first place, it doesn't really need to ask back for these details in order to decrypt the currently encrypted information.

Here are the details of decryption flow from Microsoft Docs:

[Decryption workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-overview#decryption-workflow)

[image]

> How can the disks be safeguarded from disabling encryption, through
>   RBAC ?

The real concern of who can manage VM in general or initiate/disable Disk Encryption can be controlled by assigning (or removing) the correct roles like [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner) or [Virtual Machine Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#virtual-machine-contributor) using RBAC from Azure Portal/PowerShell etc.

[image]